# How to assign click event for dynamically added span element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

html:

```
<div class="testSpanDiv"></div>
```

javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.testSpanDiv').append('<span id="testSpan">Hello</span>');
  }

  $('#testSpan').on('click', function(){
      $(this).parent().remove();
  });
```

Event is not firing while giving a click to span element added dynamically.
Event is firing if span element is statically added to the html.
Can you give any suggestion over it.

I tried like below also, but not working.

```
  $('#testSpan').on('click', '.testSpanDiv', function(){
      $(this).parent().remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this:

```
 $('.testSpanDiv').on('click', '#testSpan', function(){
  // ^^ parent div             ^^ element in which you want to bind the function
      $(this).parent().remove();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I am new to UI design, but getting a doubt even though I added while document load why span element can't be traced out. It looks weird to me.
Any link or info appreciable.

Comment: See the link that I have closed your question with.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax error try this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('.testSpanDiv').append('<span id="testSpan">Hello</span>');


   $('#testSpan').on('click', function(){
      $(this).parent().remove();
  });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7x8jbLpt/

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate the event from `body`

Also note  there are some syntax error in your code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.testSpanDiv').append('<span id="testSpan">Hello</span>');
  })

  $('body').on('click', '#testSpan', function(){
      alert("Hello")
  });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/o2urqzqm/)